# Use of Pip3 and conda to install packages on mac

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda

My Mac has already installed Anaconda.
When i want to install a package, for example, jaqs. I use

```
pip3 install jaqs
```

Then i use

```
pip3 list
```

[It seems that i have successfully installed jaqs with pip3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjiKX.jpg)

But then i type python3 in terminal, it is the python3.5 in Anaconda, rather than the System self-contained python3.5. I type

```
import jaqs
```

But no such module.(I checked the conda list, finding that no jaqs module in it)
So my question is:
How can i open the system self-contained python3.5 in terminal and import jaqs.
If not, i can't use the module in Pycharm. Sad.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

From conda docs, [Installing conda on a system that has other Python installations or packages](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html#installing-conda-on-a-system-that-has-other-python-installations-or-packages), they mention how to check which Python installation is set at the default:

```
which python
```

There are several other questions/answers on how to change it.(And it seems symbolic links are the way to go.) E.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684618/having-default-mac-python-2-7-and-anaconda-python-3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-3-on-os-x).

Alternatively, if you're not concerned with what's default Python installation, and just want to be able to use it in PyCharm: you can define which Python environment to run in PyCharm by going to "File" -> "Settings" -> "Project" -> "Project Interpreter" and either:

- from the dropdown, click "Show all" and then click green "+", or
- by clicking the cog, and then "add local".

At least then you can use an environment of your own choosing.

Comment: I mean that i want to open the original Python 3.5 in the terminal, but now everytime i type $ python3.5 , it always comes out the python3.5 with Anaconda environment, i don't want this version, because module "jaqs" is not in anaconda but the original python, can you tell me how to open the original python version? Thx.

Comment: you're welcome, and thanks for clarification. If you were able to fix it, you could also [answer your own question, which is completely fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :)